# How to get a cell selected by a specific column value in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to select the cell with order id #1968 for a dynamic table.

I have printed the table using code below , Please suggest how I can get the specific cell with value #1968 selected ?

```html
 WebElement Table_element =commonFunctions.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='active']/div/table"));
     //To locate rows of table. 
     List < WebElement > rows_table = Table_element.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
     //To calculate no of rows In table.
     int rows_count = rows_table.size();
     //Loop will execute till the last row of table.
     for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {
         //To locate columns(cells) of that specific row.
         List < WebElement > Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
         //To calculate no of columns (cells). In that specific row.
         int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
         System.out.println("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);
         //Loop will execute till the last cell of that specific row.
         for (int column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {
             // To retrieve text from that specific cell.
         celtext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
             System.out.println("Cell Value of row number " + row + " and column number " + column + " Is " + celtext);
        
         
         }
     }
```

> Result of table :  Number of cells In Row 1 are 4 Cell Value of row
>   number 1 and column number 0 Is #1975 Cell Value of row number 1 and
>   column number 1 Is SERVICE1535721248947 FOR $156 - Edited service Name
>   Cell Value of row number 1 and column number 2 Is Delivered Cell Value
>   of row number 1 and column number 3 Is Nov 5 Number of cells In Row 2
>   are 4 Cell Value of row number 2 and column number 0 Is #1971 Cell
>   Value of row number 2 and column number 1 Is service1538918641775 Cell
>   Value of row number 2 and column number 2 Is Delivered Cell Value of
>   row number 2 and column number 3 Is Oct 18 Number of cells In Row 3
>   are 4 Cell Value of row number 3 and column number 0 Is #1969 Cell
>   Value of row number 3 and column number 1 Is service1538918641775 Cell
>   Value of row number 3 and column number 2 Is Delivered Cell Value of
>   row number 3 and column number 3 Is Oct 18 Number of cells In Row 4
>   are 4 Cell Value of row number 4 and column number 0 Is #1968 Cell
>   Value of row number 4 and column number 1 Is service1538918641775 Cell
>   Value of row number 4 and column number 2 Is Delivered Cell Value of
>   row number 4 and column number 3 Is Oct 18

HTML Of the table :

```html
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Order#</th>
                                                    <th>Title</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Created</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                                                                    <tr class="entry">
                                                        <td class="gig first">
                                                            <div><a href="#">
                                                                    #1983
                                                                    </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><a href="#">SERVICE1535721248947 FOR $156 - Edited service Name</a></td>
                                                                                                                    <td class="status delivered" ><span class="label mt1 order-label-delivered">Delivered</span></td>
                                                                                                                <td class="datetime last"><div>Nov 11</div></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                                                                    <tr class="entry">
                                                        <td class="gig first">
                                                            <div><a href="#">
                                                                    #1982
                                                                    </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><a href="#">SERVICE1535721248947 FOR $156 - Edited service Name</a></td>
                                                                                                                    <td class="status delivered"><span class="label mt1 order-label-delivered">Delivered</span></td>
                                                                                                                <td class="datetime last"><div>Nov 11</div></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried find element by xpath `//td[contains(text(), '#1968')]`?

Comment: Hi @raul1ro ,  I get error using the above:

Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(text(), '#1983')]"}

However, #1983 is there in first row first column itself

Comment: Can you get us some sample of html with your table table ?

Comment: Hi @raul1ro , I have edited the question and added the code of table , Thanks

Comment: I have now used xpath("//td/div/a[contains(text(), OrderId)]" , I think it should work .

Comment: You are right. My `xpath` will look for `td` which contains that text and will ignore the text from `childs` of `td`. Your xpath should work. Also you can make it more generic. Like this: `//td[contains(text(), '#1983') or .//*[contains(text(), '#1983')]]`. Will look in `td` and in all child of `td`. This xpath will not affect your `java code` even if you change the inner `html` of `td`. P.S.: You forgot to close `<div>` which contains `<a>` with `orderId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand this correctly, but you want to iterate through the tables Order Id's and find a specific one.

How I would do it is:

```
List<WebElement> orders = this.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/a"));
```

That code will retrieve all the elements inside of the first column and add it into the orders list.

After doing that you can have an integer index variable that will track the row number of the specific element, if it exists.

```
int index = 0; 

for(WebElement elements: orders){
    index++;
   if(elements.text.equals("#1968"){
       //Here you can click on the link or do whatever... 
this.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[index]/td[1]/div/a")).click();
 }

}
```

I cant remember the exact syntax for selenium but I know I iterated through a list of elements and clicked on a specific one according to my data set.

Please note that sometimes selenium driver returns an error for not finding an element, use

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.getDriver(), 30)
```

to expand the duration.

Another helpful thing to use is the Action class, so here is the better solution:

```
Action act = new Action(this.getDriver());
act.click(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid"))).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my current project I have application, where are many tables. I usually defining separate columns as

`List<WebElement> nameColumnList, List<WebElement> statusColumnList`

Then I am iterating for Name column, searching for row number, which has name, which I need. Then, using this number, I am getting text from Status column and verifying it's value. This how I am getting all values from table and clicking or validating them.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Grab the table 
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table")); 

// Now get all the TR elements from the table 
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 

// And iterate over them, getting the cells 
for (WebElement row : allRows) { 
    List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

    for (WebElement cell : cells) {

        if(cell.getText().equals("2010")) {
            String[] ColData = row.getText().split(" ");
            // Split the row text to get the mentioned column details
            System.out.println(ColData[2]);
            System.out.println(ColData[3]);
            System.out.println(ColData[4]);             
        }
        if(cell.getText().equals("Saudi Arabia")) {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/a")).click();

        }
        System.out.println(cell.getText());

    }
}
```